# Why is this code not able to push_back a char into a vector<char>?

Tags: c++, vector, char

I want to `push_back` a character into a vector and print it, but I don't know why it is not getting printed.

I don't understand what to do, as the program is compiling and returning 0.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<char> A(4);
  char d = 's';
  A.push_back(d);
  // for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  { cout << "first element is" << A[0]; }
  return 0;
}
```

Output I am getting in the CodeBlocks IDE:

```
first element is
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.444 s
```

Comment: "*why is this code not able to push_back char into vector<char>*" What makes you think it doesn't work? What's the result you intend to observe?

Comment: I think OP's problem is that he can't see the expected output from `cout`. That is probably because the application is ending instantly. If you are running it under windows, try to execute the program through a command prompt window and you will be able to see your output.

Comment: @Dean Seo i tried to print s it didn't get printed i got the answer below

Comment: You accepted an answer. That's how one symbolizes the issue as resolved for them. No need to do anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with your implementation lies in

> vector  A(4);

and

> A.push_back(d);

lines.

When you construct a vector with default size of 4, ***it means, A[0] to A[3] indices are already allocated***.
Next when you are doing push_back(), you are pushing the element in the next possible index, which in your case is 4.

Hence, ***A.push_back(d);*** -> What it is doing is simply allocate A[4] and, assign A[4] = 's';

just print A[4], and you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

you print the A[0] value but 's' is push back as A[4] value

by using a debugger you can see this

define vector in this way your problem will be solved

```
vector <char> A;
```